# preg_match_all() - Trouble getting a string to match in foreach loop

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a similar problem to the one that is answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684920/regex-to-get-float-from-a-string).

When I test the regex provided as the answer in that post it worked as expected:

```
  $str = 'Days - £9.20 to £11.20 Sat - £11.80 Sun - £13.30';            

  preg_match_all("/£\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?/", $str, $matches);                    

  print_r($matches);

  // Produces
  Array
  (
     [0] => Array
        (
          [0] => £9.20
          [1] => £10.20
          [2] => £11.80
         )
   )
```

The problem comes when I try to use this to process data from a CSV that i've converted to an array in a foreach loop:

```
foreach($arrJobs as $job)
{
    $str = $job['payDetails1'] . ' ' . $job['payDetails2'];                     

    // Try to find salary from string           

    preg_match_all("/£\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?/", $str, $matches);

    print_r($matches);                  
}

// In this example the output from every item is an empty array:

 Array
 (
   [0] => Array
       (
       )

  )
```

The string I used to test the function in the first example was gotten by echoing out the value of $str in the second example and copying and pasting it.

I don't understand why the same string returns different results? And why when I paste the string into a variable it works fine but when the string is retrieved from the CSV no matches are found?

Comment: what is output of this line `$str = $job['payDetails1'] . ' ' . $job['payDetails2'];` ???

Comment: Most likely because of the encoding of the CSV file. Be aware that `preg_match_all` treats its arguments as sequences of bytes (unless you use `/u`), so the pound sign in your source file must match any pound sign in the input *bytewise*, not just character-wise. Which means your source and the CSV must be saved using the same encoding, unless you write code to account for differences. I 'm picking on the pound sign because it is the only character outside the ASCII range.

Comment: You're sure that $str is well formed in the second case ?

Comment: @Yogesh The same as in my first example. 'Days - £9.20 to £11.20 Sat - £11.80 Sun - £13.30'. Obviously each row isn't the same, but at least for one loop it is the same.

Comment: @Fry_95 - The first example was just copied and pasted from the output of the second example, so it should be no different.

Comment: @JamieDevine: Start the expression with `/\xc2?\xa3\s*` and tell us what happens. **IMPORTANT**: Use single quotes around the expression, otherwise you have to double each backslash (this is a bug you already have there)!

Comment: @Jon That works! Thank you, could you possibly explain what the first part of the Regex does? Or point me in the direction of where I can find out? If you answer the question rather than reply in a comment I can accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @JamieDevine: I added a detailed answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer derived from comments and feedback above]

#### The problem

The problem here is that your source file and your CSV input are not saved with the same character encoding.

All built-in string functions in PHP (including the PCRE functions when the `/u` flag is not used) operate blindly on sequences of bytes and do not recognize characters as such. This means that for scripts that contain characters outside the ASCII range the runtime behavior will change depending on which encoding the script is saved in, since these characters will be converted to bytes differently for each and every encoding used in practice. Your script contains one such character: the [pound sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a3/index.htm).

#### A quick solution

Assuming that the possible encodings in play here are [ISO 8859-1 (Western European)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) and [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8), all the remaining characters matched by your regular expression have the same representation in both encodings so they will present no problem. So let's see what we can do about the pound sign.

Typically you would solve this problem by replacing the literal `£` with an alternation group that covers all of the character's encodings.

```
        POUND SIGN ( £ )
when encoded in    is represented as
------------------------------------
ISO 8859-1         0xA3
UTF-8              0xC2 0xA3
```

So that would be `(\xa3|\xc2\xa3)` -- the first part covers ISO 8859-1 and the second UTF-8. However, seeing as both parts end in `\xa3` the same result can be also had with `\xc2?\xa3` (making the `\xc2` prefix optional).

Therefore you can solve your problem in a somewhat quick and dirty manner by changing the code to

```
preg_match_all('/\xc2?\xa3\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?/', $str, $matches);
```

#### A better solution

The best solution however would be to always work in UTF-8. To do this, you would need to

1. Save your script as UTF-8
2. Make sure that the input CSV is either in UTF-8 to begin with or that you convert it to UTF-8 before processing (you can use [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to do this)

This way you can go back to saving a literal pound sign in your script, and still be safe in the knowledge that it will work correctly no matter what the input encoding for your CSV data.