# php preg_match_all having issues with £ sign and UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-match-all

I have a similar issue to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580401/preg-match-all-trouble-getting-a-string-to-match-in-foreach-loop). I am getting from another service a text containing 'BEGIN--- £144.23 --- £151.23 --- Please pay £161.23 by 25 Jun 2013 ---END' which I want to parse.

Here is my script (with the text containing the sequence above being represented by `$text`, an array of sentences line by line):

```
$myText = utf8_decode(implode(' --- ', $text));
$myExtract = return_between($myText, 'BEGIN', 'END', EXCL);
$allGBP = parse_array(myExtract, '£', ' ');
```

With the 2 functions:

`return_between` is basically a combination of strpos and substr and returns the extract between 'BEGIN' and 'END'.

```
function parse_array($string, $beg_tag, $close_tag)
{
    preg_match_all("($beg_tag(.*)$close_tag)siU", $string, $matching_data);
    return $matching_data[0];
}
```

On wamp the script works and $allGBP is an array containing '£144.23', '£151.23' and '£161.23'. On my server the script does not work and $allGBP is empty. `$allGBP = parse_array(myExtract, '&pound;', ' ');` doesn't work either.

It looks like the UTF-8 is broken at some point and that throw preg_match_all off (based on the other question I found) but I am confused as to why this would only happen on the server and not also on wamp. If I remove`utf8_decode` at the start, the £ sign become Â£.

Any suggestion?

EDIT: just in case: it's PHP5.3 on both wamp and server.

Answer (score 0):

In the instruction:

```
preg_match_all("($beg_tag(.*)$close_tag)siU", $string, $matching_data);
```

change the delimiters

```
preg_match_all("/$beg_tag(.*)$close_tag/siU", $string, $matching_data);
```

Comment: Thanks. However it now doesn't work at all anymore. This is a function that I got from a book and that works for a lot of other parts of my script - as long as I don't try to use "£" as a tag. So I don't think it's the cause.